# How to solve the electric box riddle in Ace Ventura Game?

Tags: ace-ventura

In the game AceVentura there is an electric box

[image]

One has to press green/red + hand gear and red/blue + hand gear (see minute 55:14):

How are you supposed to know as a player that you have to hit those combinations?

As there are 4 buttons, this gives 16 possibilities. Are you just supposed to try out all combinations? Or is there any hint guiding you to the correct colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this guide](https://www.walkthroughking.com/text/aceventura.aspx), you have to:

> use the information you got from the satellite dish outside

You can get that moment at 44:00 from your linked video:

[image]

Red button clearly means it disables electric circuits or opens things (since it's used in both riddles), but I can't see the link between a shoe and the prods.

Comment: Ah.. It makes sense, the yellow icon represents the power fence and the blue shoe represents the shoe that kicks the dogs (and causes them to run). I missed this part of the game, apparently you can just walk through without the screwdriver and this board

Comment: Wait, its not red and yellow but red and green that disables the electric fence.. Well no idea how this matches